# Dyanmic Endorsement Policy

Tags: linux, hyperledger-fabric, blockchain, hyperledger

I am actually new to Hyperldeger fabric framework. I am working on research project where I want to select specific Endorsers from my end. Can we really do that ?
As far as I know, the Endorsement policy will be always in the syntax of "AND(Org1MSP.peer,Org2MSP.peer)". But I want to select the individual peers of the organization and currently it seems impossible. Is there any other workaround ?
Please put some light on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your client, you can choose to select whatever endorser peers you prefer for each transaction through [Transaction.setEndorserPeers(peers)](https://hyperledger.github.io/fabric-sdk-node/release-2.2/module-fabric-network.Transaction.html#setEndorsingPeers__anchor). But it is a client decision, not a network restriction. Another client could choose any other endorser selection strategy (as long as it fulfills the endorsement policies of the chaincode). At endorsement policy level, you cannot require specific peers.

Comment: Hi, I have specified Any as my endorsement policy and I am getting this error 2022-02-06T15:07:49.625Z - error: [Transaction]: Error: No valid responses from any peers. Errors:
    at newEndorsementError (/home/pranay/fabric-samples/fabcar/javascript/node_modules/fabric-network/lib/transaction.js:53:12)
    at getResponsePayload (/home/pranay/fabric-samples/fabcar/javascript/node_modules/fabric-network/lib/transaction.js:21:23)